# Nuxt3 Vite server port

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I need to config server port for Nuxt3. I try to do it so:

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt3'

export default defineNuxtConfig(
  vite: {
    server: {
      port: 5000,
    },
  },
})
```

But it doesn't work. How to set server port in Nuxt3?

Comment: Btw, as a side note since the RC1, you only need `import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'` (no need for `nuxt3`). As shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/nuxt3-rc/#vite--webpack

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [told here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/1290#discussioncomment-1510020), this is currently not supported.

Change it like this

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --port=5678", // here
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.1"
  }
}
```

---

Here is how to change the port for production: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/1884#discussioncomment-1631668

Comment: product  **PORT=5000 node .output/server/index.mjs**

Comment: The `devServer` configuration is available to set the port. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76281156/3247405

Answer (score 10):

As of the time of writing the answer, you can now define the port in your `nuxt.config` as follows:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
  },
})
```

[Source](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#port)

Answer (score 5):

Create a `.env` file in your project root:

```
PORT=5000
```

---

By doing that, you set the `PORT` environment variable which Nuxt picks up at start.

Answer (score 4):

My solution for `dev` and `production` mode in all platforms (windows, Linux, MacOS) :

1. Install the `cross-env` to support cross platforms.

```bash
sudo npm i cross-env -g
```

2. Edit your project `package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --port=8001",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "cross-env PORT=8001 node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.4"
  },
}
```

3. Run the app

```bash
yarn run preview
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PM2, set the port on ecosystem.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'NuxtAppName',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max',
      script: './.output/server/index.mjs',
    port: 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this in your `ecosystem.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'NuxtApp',
      port: 3001,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: '1',
      script: './.output/server/index.mjs',
      args: 'preview',
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true, even though theoretically you could do

```
Server: {
   port: 'xxxx'
}
```

or `host: '0'` in order to expose to the local network, in the definition of server you can see:

> Use environment variables or top level server options to configure Nuxt server.

`server?: Omit<ServerOptions, 'port' | 'host'>;`

So even if you set those, they won't be taken into account.

Solve like @kissu said by changing package.json to something like
`"dev": "nuxt dev --host=0 --port=3000"`