# How to change Nuxt 3 Port

Tags: typescript, server, nuxt.js, port, .env

I tried the old solution but it not works any more, then I tried to read the nuxt 3 documentation, and it is not actually update.

So how to change How to change Nuxt 3 Port  without change dev script like @kissu did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139073/nuxt3-vite-server-port#:%7E:text=3-,Answers,-Sorted%20by%3A)

I tried the old solution

on /.nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig(
  
    server: {
      port: 8080,
    },
  
})
```

and I got http://localhost:3000

Edit:

I found the way using .env file

into your .env file  ([project_root] /.env)

```
PORT=8080
```

Nuxt 3 detect it automaticaly from your env variable .

Answer (score 13):

In Nuxt3 `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devServer: {
    port: 8000
  }
})
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this doesn't work for me in Nuxt 3. It still uses 5000.

Comment: @pmrotule how do you run dev server? Check your package.json scripts for any port settings there.

Answer (score 8):

to change production port after `npm run build`

and run `NITRO_PORT=4000 node .output/server/index.mjs`

Listening http://[::]:4000

or using pm2 ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'NuxtAppName',
      port: '3000',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: 'max',
      script: './.output/server/index.mjs'
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt3 to change default PORT

for Development Environment  , in package.json

```
 "dev": "nuxt dev -p 3020",
```

for Production Environment, create .env file in root folder ( if not exist )

```
PORT=3200
```

This will work when you run command

```
npm run preview
```

Answer (score 1):

Title: Nuxt3 doesn't read PORT from .env file after npm run build

Problem:
After running `npm run build` in Nuxt3, the application doesn't take the PORT configuration from the .env file. Instead, it picks up environment variables from the system environment.

Solution:
To ensure that Nuxt3 reads the PORT configuration from the .env file, you need to export your environment variables to the system. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open your terminal.
2. Navigate to your Nuxt3 project directory.
3. Execute the following command:

```bash
export PORT=4000
```

Replace `4000` with your desired port number if needed.

For Production:
If you're deploying your Nuxt3 application to production, you can export all environment variables from the .env file using the following script:

```bash
export $(xargs < .env)
```

This command reads the variables from the .env file and exports them to the system environment.

This Command should add in the docker file or any deployment steps that will help you.

By following these steps, Nuxt3 will read the PORT configuration from the .env file as expected, both during development and production.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).